# Can I change the Event Listener on PayPal buttons to activate an easter egg and then bring it back to original later?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox, event-listener

I am trying to activate an easter egg on my website when someone types a specific amount to donate.

Is there an option to over-ride PayPal button for that? So if the user clicks on Pay With PayPal instead of the PayPal pop up he will get a custom event (opening Bootstrap Modal in my case). And then bring it back to normal if he types a regular amount.

First is it possible? And second, and maybe more important, is it fine by PayPal or they can view it as a security problem?

My code (the paypal part) looks like this:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=CLIENT ID"></script>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
paypal
  .Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              value: document.querySelector("#donate-amount").value,
            },
          },
        ],
      });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
        let submitForm = document.createElement('form');
        submitForm.method = "POST";
        submitForm.action = "/DonateSucess";
        document.body.appendChild(submitForm);
        submitForm.submit();
      });
    },
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container"); // Display payment options on your web page

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with validation using the onClick function and `actions.disable()` or `.enable()`, followed by whatever other logic you wish to trigger.

See the documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/validation/ for some examples

Comment: Hi, I couldn't really understand how to use it for my needs, as it seem to only disable the button, actions.disable mean that it won't redirect to paypal or that the button won't be "clicked" at all?

Comment: After testing, yes, it's exactly what I needed, thank you very much!!